# Service bus dead lettered message without reason

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm having problems with messages ending up in the deadletter subqueue without a reason.

When peeking messages in a deadletter queue (with "Service Bus Explorer") one can often see the reason for the deatlettering, but in this case (described below) there's no reason.

I have a topic, with 2 subscriptions. One of the subscription have a SQLFilter where:

```
State = 'Evaluate'
```

And the other subscription has a `'AutoForward' = mymessages` and one or multiple rules, where each rule has both a CorrelationFilter and a SqlAction, ex:

```
CorrelationId = 'A'
Action = 'Set [sys].SessionId = 'A'
```

Most of the time this works perfectly, but sometimes a message or two ends up in the deadletter queue of this second subscription.

This subscription has:

```
EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = false
EnableDeadLetteringOnFilerEvaluationError = false
MaxDeliveryCount = 99999
```

When peeking the deadlettered message in SBE, it has:

```
DeliveryCount = 0
MessageExpiration = 2018-01-01
MessageId = X
```

And when viewing my logs, i can see that i actually received a message with MessageId = X from 'mymessages'. And once the message is received, the correspondig rule in the second subscription is deleted.

It seems like the message that ended up in the deadletter queue is a duplicate?!

Can someone please explain what's actually happening, why is the message being deadlettered?

(There's no code in my solution that 'manually' deadletters messages)

Comment: Have you tried a different namespace to confirm the same behaviour?

Comment: Im having a hard time to reproduce it since I can't understand why or when it's happening, but no, I haven't tried another namespace.  Why do you think that would help?

Comment: If this is something you can repro with another namespace, then it's a coffee issue and we can focus on that.

Comment: Code issue :) wish it would be as easy as a coffee issue.